# Is there anyway to scale an image to fit to the bottom of the screen like a footer?

Tags: html, css

[Right now it is not covering the whole width of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Kc5.jpg)

I have searched and tried the solutions for all those with a similar questions.
It either pulled the image right or left and made it bigger.
If anyone has any ideas that would be great.
I'm a student and beginner at coding.

Comment: What is your current mark up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to use `background-size: cover;` in your css to get the image to cover the full width of your area. It is the most flexible way of doing it, but it will cut your image at the bottom and on the sides depending on how small the screen is and how tall the container element is. You can of course adjust this with css background-position.

Here you have some other ideas for how to solve your problem: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

background-size:cover; will fix this